# How to split in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I am using VB.NET code.

I have got the below string.

```
http://localhost:3282/ISS/Training/SearchTrainerData.aspx
```

Now I want to split the above string with "/" as well. I want to store the value **SearchTrainerData.aspx** in a variable.

In my case

```
Dim str as String

str = "SearchTrainerData.aspx"
```

What would be the code which will split the above string and further store it in a variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-4) function takes characters, which VB.NET represents by appending a 'c' to the end of a one-character string:

```
Dim sentence = "http://localhost:3282/ISS/Training/SearchTrainerData.aspx"
Dim words = sentence.Split("/"c)
Dim lastWord = words(words.length - 1)
```

Comment: @Dan You're right. I was answering the title question as opposed to the general URL question. Feel free to edit it to include a link to the proper method, but do leave the existing code because that's what searchers will expect to find based on the title.

Answer (score 6):

Try to use the function [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-4).

Comment: @Solution: save everyone the time, including yourself, and just Google for "vb.net string split". There are tons of useful results. It's generally considerate to do some research before posting on SO.

Answer (score 5):

Your "string" is obviously a URL which means you should use the [System.Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) class.

```
Dim url As Uri = New Uri("http://localhost:3282/ISS/Training/SearchTrainerData.aspx")
Dim segments As String() = url.Segments
Dim str As String = segments(segments.Length - 1)
```

This will also allow you to get all kinds of other interesting information about your "string" without resorting to manual (and error-prone) parsing.

Answer (score 1):

Use [split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx). You call it on the string instance, passing in a char array of the delimiters, and it returns to you an array of strings. Grab the last element to get your "SearchTrainerData.aspx."

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you are actually looking for is the System.Uri Class. Which makes all string splitting that you are looking for obsolete.

[MSDN Documentation for System.Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.uri.aspx)

```
Uri url = new Uri ("http://...");
String[] parts = url.Segments;
```