# Split string by <br> vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have an html Address line like this:

```
Addressline1<br>Addressline2<br>...
```

How can I split them into an array ?

I have used this code but it only returns some characters

```
                    Dim addressLine As String() = "Address1<br>Address2<br>".Split(New String() {"<br>"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

                    For index As Integer = 0 To addressLine.Count - 1
                        Dim address As String = "Address" + (index + 1).ToString()
                        Console.WriteLine(address(index))
                    Next
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to split in vb.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560401/how-to-split-in-vb-net)

Comment: You have the answer right in your question. Split

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your split works, but your loop makes no sense (not sure what you were trying to do with this). If you fix this, it will output the correct values:

```
For index As Integer = 0 To addressLine.Count - 1
    Console.WriteLine(addressLine(index))
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim Address As String() = addressLine.Split("<br>")
```