# How to split a string in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to split in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560401/how-to-split-in-vb-net)

I have a string "1- ABCDEFGH - HIJKLMN - 1"

I just want to get "1" out of the string (The first number before "-" in the string)

[image]

Comment: Have you tried String.Split? There are other ways too...

Comment: You're not clear in your question : You said you wanna "split" (which usually indicates splitting according to a specific separator) the string, and then you tell us you wanna "get out" the first character. What is your expected result ? "1" or "- ABCDEFGH - HIJKLMN - 1" ?

Answer (score 2):

Use [String.Split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx)

```
Dim s = "1- ABCDEFGH - HIJKLMN - 1"
Dim one = s.Split("-"c)(0) ' one = 1
```

Comment: BigYellowCactus, "First is not a member of syste.array" This is wat i see

Comment: @Anuya `First` is an extension method. You should see it if you are running at least .Net Framework 3.5, have a reference to `System.Core` and imported the `System.Linq` namespace. Anyway, I have changed the code to use an index instead of that method, which will always work.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can treat a string in .Net like an array, so you can get the first character like so:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim myString As String = "1- ABCDEFGH - HIJKLMN -1"
    Dim firstCharacter As String = myString(0)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

String stringPart = myString.Substring(0,myString.IndexOf('-')) will put in stringPart all characters beginning from the start of the string (index 0) up to the first character '-' (not included)